# Parsing data from a text file into an array

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have a flat text file that contains the following data;

> ```
> Following are the names and ages in a text file.
> ```

```
26|Rachel
29|Chris
26|Nathan
```

The data is kept on a server (e.g http://domain.com/info.dat), I'd like to read this text file and insert it into an array (age and name). I'd like to ignore the first line (Following are....).

I've sorted the code to grab the data file using a webclient and the code to open the dat file using streamreader as follows;

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
                {
                    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                    {
                        string[] channels = Text.Split('|');

                        foreach (string s in channels)
                        {  

                        }
                    }
                }
```

The problem with the above code is when it comes to inputting it into an array with the correct columns. Could anyone give me some pointers?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about an answer that uses some LINQ:

```
var results = from str in File.ReadAllLines(path).Skip(1)
              where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)
              let data = str.Split('|')
              where data.Length == 2
              select new Person { Age = Int32.Parse(data[0], NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), Name = data[1] };
```

`results` is now `IEnumerable<Person>` which you can do `ToList` or `ToArray` on to get a `List<Person>` or `Person[]`, or you can simply use the results with a `foreach` loop.

**UPDATE:** here is the `Person` class needed to make this more functional.

```
public class Person
{
   public int Age { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: FUNKY! But for some reason I like it... even though I can't, for the life of me, understand LINQ... it's THE most impenetrable, unnatural, gowd-awful syntax I've ever encountered (excluding REGEX's, obviously).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, i'm having issues with this code in that the IDE doesnt like Person. Is there a reference i need for this?

Comment: Nathan: Oh. From one of the other answers you mentioned that you wanted to put the data into a `Person` class. I assumed you already had it at the ready. I'll address that in an update.

Comment: @corlettk: I find the LINQ syntax so natural to read. It's like a sentence.

Comment: Sorry about that, i was being a bit dumb! i had changed the Person class name. Thank you.

Comment: @Matt: Natural? What's your native language, and is "Matt" your real name... I've got it... LINQ is a secret Russian invasion!!! Head for the hills!... Like I said... I really do like that solution though. In fact I've just boosted a copy for my "examples cache". It's almost elegant. The only clunker for me is the where clause just LOOKS out of place.

Comment: This is a fine answer, just note that the call to File.ReadAllLines(path) will read the entire file into memory. For this scenario this might not be a problem but other cases with huge amounts of data this could pose a potential problem.

Comment: i've just noticed that some of the data i'm reading will have NULL values. when trying to read it using this LINQ solution i get an error stating "input string was not in correct format". I presume i'm getting this error because i'm not checking for NULL value's? thanks

Comment: i presume i need to do something with the following line:  where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)

Comment: Do you have any blank lines in your text file, or perhaps lines not obeying the `age|name` format? I didn't put much error checking in the query.

Comment: I have some entries that are missing the name. e.g age| Would the query try to enter a NULL object or ""? I prefer it to just return "" if it's NULL. thanks

Comment: Did you try it out? As written, the query will insert an empty string for the name in the case of e.g. "45|", because the Split method was not told to remove empties. Your `Person` class could also validate its properties in the `set` method.

Comment: I did, it's working now. Thanks for your reply and sorry for the late one!

Comment: Sorry about this i have another problem. When the linq statement finds a NULL entry for the age (data such as |Nathan), i get the "input string was not in correct format" error. I presume it's trying to put a NULL value into an int. how do i go about sorting this? thanks

Comment: You could use `Int32.TryParse`, but the query will change. You will also need an `int` variable outside of the query.

Comment: is there a way without changing the query?

Comment: Query variables cannot be used as `out` parameters, so a variable external to the query must be used for `TryParse`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. (There is no error checking, you might want to check for errors when parsing the age etc.

```
class Person
{
  string Name {get;set;}
  int Age {get;set;}
}

List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
string line;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
  sr.ReadLine();
  while ((line == sr.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    string[] channels = line.Split('|');    
    people.Add(new Person() {Age=int.Parse(channels[0]), Name=channels[1]});       
  }
}
```

Comment: That's about what I was thinking... Except, why is that people create List's called "array" and arrays called "list"? Just curious ;-)

Comment: @corlettk, to be honest I normally would not have called it array, but in this case I did so that the OP could correlate that to the terminology in the question. The OP wanted an array so I am showing by convention where I am addressing that requirement though not with an array, I have a strange mind!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use Dictionary and not Array to store the data. 
Sample code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("filename");
Dictionary<int,string> dict = new Dictionary<int,string>();
string line = "";
fs.ReadLine(); //skip the first line
while( (line = fs.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string parts = line.split("|".ToCharArray());
    dict.Add(int.Parse(parts[0]), parts[1]);
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd just create a List<Person>; where Person has attributes Name and Age... unless I had a REASON to use some other datastructure, such as a Map... Like for instance I didn't know at compile time what the attributes of Person are... But in this case I do.

Comment: Agree, creating a strong type to represent data is also an option.